# Does cargo install have an equivalent update command?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I used `cargo install` to globally install a package, such as *rustfmt* or *racer*.

How can I update the installed package without first deleting it ( `cargo uninstall`) and then running `cargo install` again.

Is there an update command?

Comment: Nope. You can discuss it in [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2082) issue.

Comment: Rerunning the initial `cargo install thing` will cause it to be updated.

Comment: @BallpointBen yep, this is what the accepted answer indicates

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As of Rust 1.41.0, you can use the following command to update crates to their latest version:

```
cargo install <crate>
```

This came from pull request [#6798 (Add install-upgrade)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/6798) and was stabilized in [#7560 (Stabilize install-upgrade)](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7560).

#### How does it work?

Instead of failing when `cargo install` detects a package is already installed, it will upgrade if the versions don't match, or do nothing (exit 0) if it is considered "up-to-date".

#### Forcing an upgrade / re-installation

The following command will **always** uninstall, download and compile the latest version of the crate - even if there's no newer version available. Under normal circumstances the `install-upgrade` feature should be preferred as it does save time and bandwidth if there's no new version of the crate.

```
cargo install --force <crate>
```

#### Documentation

Further information can be found in the GitHub issue [rust-lang/cargo#6797](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6797) and [in the official documentation chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html?highlight=upgrade#cargo-install).

Comment: Will this also compile them with nightly?

Comment: This is now stabilized, and the default behavior. You no longer need to use the nightly channel or provide the `-Z install-upgrade` argument. https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/7560

Comment: If you wish to update all packages a simple shell command such as `cargo install --list | grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]* v[0-9.]*:$' | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs cargo install` would suffice

Comment: Automatic upgrade does not seem to be the default behavior in Rust 1.55.0; I had `wasm-pack 0.10.0` installed, but when I tried to update it to `0.10.1` using `cargo install wasm-pack` I got an error: `error: binary 'wasm-pack' already exists in destination` and had to use `--force`.

Answer (score 223):

There is no such command in vanilla `cargo` (well, there's `cargo install` but that's for dependencies), but since `cargo` supports [third-party subcommands](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/wiki/Third-party-cargo-subcommands) there is an answer: the [`cargo-update` crate](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-update).

Install as usual with

```
cargo install cargo-update
```

then use

```
cargo install-update -a
```

to update all installed packages, for more usage information and examples see the [`cargo install-update` manpage](https://rawcdn.githack.com/nabijaczleweli/cargo-update/man/cargo-install-update-config.1.html).

<sub>Disclaimer: am author</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for this utility!  It's fantastic!  And this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @BenSandeen Well, that's the general treatment answers that are a year late v0v

Comment: needs `cmake` to be installed

Comment: @rofrol As is clearly outlaid in [the Installation sexion of the Manpage](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/cargo-update#installation)

Comment: "well, there's cargo install but that's for dependencies" actually `cargo install` can now be used to install crates globally: `Install a Rust binary. Default location is $HOME/.cargo/bin`

Comment: This should be a standard feature.

Comment: @MichaelMantion for real, it's insane in this day and age of security holes abound, that somebody decided to add a way to install binaries on your PATH but didn't think to provide a way to update them.

Answer (score 30):

A solution I've found is to add the `--force` flag to the install command.  For example `cargo install --force clippy`.  This will effectively re-install the latest version.

Comment: In recent versions of `cargo`, using `--force` is no longer necessary to update a crate

Answer (score 27):

Here is a one-liner to update all installed Cargo crates, except those installed from a local folder:

```sh
cargo install $(cargo install --list | egrep '^[a-z0-9_-]+ v[0-9.]+:$' | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

Explanation:

- List installed packages
- Filter to lines which contain package names and versions, and exclude ones with filesystem paths
- Cut those lines to only include the package name
- `cargo install` with the resulting package names

Comment: Thank you for an answer without external dependencies.

Comment: `cargo install $(cargo install --list | awk '/:$/ { print $1; }')`

Comment: If you'll pardon the golf, `cargo install --list | egrep -o '^[^ ]+'` is a bit shorter for listing the installed packages. Are there ever non-indented lines that are not packages?

Answer (score 1):

I use the command

```
cargo install --locked $(cat $CARGO_HOME/.crates2.json | jq -r '.installs | keys[] | split(" ")[0]')
```

You need `jq` to run this command. I use [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72975377/1772898) to reliably get the installed packages.

Please note that i have used [`--locked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html#dealing-with-the-lockfile) here. Without `--locked` few builds may fail. For example, as of today, if you use `cargo install-update -a`, you will get a message like "Failed to update pueue, ripgrep_all." (Here, replace pueue, ripgrep_all with packages that need `--locked`).

Another thing is, we may have some dependencies to update the installed package. For that i made a function which will first get the dependencies then update the installed package.

Here is a sample function for fish shell.

```
function rust_update_packages
    # cargo install --locked ripgrep_all
    # cargo install --locked pueue
    # Alacritty Dependencies
    apt install -y cmake pkg-config libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxkbcommon-dev python3
    cargo install --locked $(cat $CARGO_HOME/.crates2.json | jq -r '.installs | keys[] | split(" ")[0]')
end
```

For other shell, only the function syntax will change, the body of the function will remain same.