# How do I list all of the packages I've installed globally with cargo install?

Tags: rust-cargo

I've installed several CLI tools using `cargo install` (for instance, ripgrep). How do I see a list of all the crates I've downloaded using `cargo install`? Sort of like `apt list --installed` but for `cargo`?

Answer (score 83):

The command line

```
cargo help install
```

produces detailed help information. Among others, it lists common EXAMPLES, e.g.

> 3. View the list of installed packages:
>
>    ```
>    cargo install --list
>    ```

This lists all installed packages alongside their versions and the collection of binaries contained. Doing this is superior to other proposed solutions as packages can contain multiple binaries (e.g. [`cargo-edit`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit)) or have a binary name that doesn't match the crate name (such as [`ripgrep`](https://crates.io/crates/ripgrep)).

Just be careful not to type `cargo install list` as that is trying to install the [`list`](https://crates.io/crates/list) package, which thankfully errors out at the time of writing (as opposed to installing a rogue binary).

Answer (score 9):

`ls ~/.cargo/bin/`

The binary files are stored here, so listing all the files in this directory will give you all the global cargo crates you've installed.

Comment: The installed binary name doesn't necessarily match the package name, e.g. `cargo install cargo-edit` gives you `cargo-add` and `cargo-rm`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the list shown by `cargo install --list`, then please check:

```bash
cat $CARGO_HOME/.crates.toml
cat $CARGO_HOME/.crates2.json | jq .
```

Please note that `.crates2.json` is in json format.

To list out the installed package names you could run:

```bash
cat $CARGO_HOME/.crates2.json | jq -r '.installs | keys[] | split(" ")[0]'
```

Comment: Helpful answer, but for me the path was `$CARGO_HOME/.crates2.json` (not inside the `bin` directory).