# what is the command to update all my rust packages

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I installed several rust applications using:

```
cargo install fd-find sd ripgrep rga bat tealdeer exa git-delta du-dust
```

Is there any command like `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` which I can use to update the packages.

Comment: Your are looking for https://docs.rs/cargo-update/7.0.1/cargo_update/index.html

Comment: Duplicate of [Does cargo install have an equivalent update command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484361/does-cargo-install-have-an-equivalent-update-command). 

Bash one-liner to update all rust packages: `cargo install $(cargo install --list | egrep '^[a-z0-9_-]+ v[0-9.]+:$' | cut -f1 -d' ')`. Credits to [David Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4247209/david-bailey) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049504/1291371).

Comment: _One does not simply update all of their cargo packages._

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a optional subcommand [`cargo-update`](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/cargo-update) to do that:

```sh
cargo install cargo-update
cargo install-update -a
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Cargo subcommand can be used for checking and applying updates to installed executables.

**You can try cargo-update**

```
cargo install cargo-update
```

**General syntax**

```
cargo install-update [OPTIONS] [PACKAGE…]
```

**Update all installed packages :**

```
cargo install-update -af
```

**Update only selective packages :**

```
cargo install-update fd-find sd ripgrep rga bat tealdeer exa git-delta du-dust
```

Reference : https://docs.rs/cargo-update/7.0.1/cargo_update/index.html